# AsyncTask returning results before second AsyncTask starts

Tags: android

I have read similar topics but not getting a clear answer.
My app uses AsyncTask in loop to calculate distances between cities. Because of that my app commmunicates with Google Maps API many times. Problem is that the variable "i" of loop takes final value  **before** results come back. How can i ensure that second AsyncTask will execute after **results** from first AsyncTask are back;

Part of code...

```
for(n=0;n<b-1;n++){                     

                if(!itinList1.get(n+1).get("username").equals(username)){   

                if(itinList1.get(n).get("username").equals(username)){                      


            origin_lat = itinList1.get(n).get("start_lat_pro").toString();
            origin_lng = itinList1.get(n).get("start_lng_pro").toString();
            destination_lat = itinList1.get(n).get("final_lat_pro").toString();
            destination_lng = itinList1.get(n).get("final_lng_pro").toString();

            for (w = n; w < b; w++) {                       

                markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();             

                waypoint1_lat = itinList1.get(w).get("start_lat_pro").toString();
                waypoint1_lng = itinList1.get(w).get("start_lng_pro").toString();
                waypoint2_lat = itinList1.get(w).get("final_lat_pro").toString();
                waypoint2_lng = itinList1.get(w).get("final_lng_pro").toString();

                LatLng origin1 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(origin_lat),
                        Double.parseDouble(origin_lng));
                LatLng destination = new LatLng(
                        Double.parseDouble(destination_lat),
                        Double.parseDouble(destination_lng));
                LatLng waypoint1 = new LatLng(
                        Double.parseDouble(waypoint1_lat),
                        Double.parseDouble(waypoint1_lng));
                LatLng waypoint2 = new LatLng(
                        Double.parseDouble(waypoint2_lat),
                        Double.parseDouble(waypoint2_lng));


                markerPoints.add(origin1);
                markerPoints.add(destination);
                markerPoints.add(waypoint1);
                markerPoints.add(waypoint2);

                LatLng or = markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);


                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(or, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();     

                downloadTask.execute(url);                      

                if(itinList1.get(w+1).get("username").equals(username)){    

                    break;
                }

            }           

            }
                } else {
                    itinList1.get(n).put("diff", String.valueOf(0));

            }               
                }
```

I know that nesting AsyncTask is not a very good idea but it is dificcult to change it now

Comment: start the second asynctask in the postexecute of first asynctask

Comment: there are many AsyncTask  that are waiting to execute...

Comment: Do you know about status of AsyncTask?? you can use `getStatus()` checks whether the the `AsyncTask` is `pending`, `running`, or `finished`.and when finsh start your new task

Comment: I am with Pramod here, just start one AsyncTask in the onPostExecute of the other. If you need access to member variables that you do not have there, you can use the approach of Sagars answer.

Comment: I think that getStatus() guaranties the sequence of execution. I don't have problem with that but with the fact that they start to be executed with the right sequence after loop finishes

Answer (score 1):

Read about `Callback` mechanism in java.

1) Implement an interface e.g

```
interface OnAsyncOneComplete {
    void onProcessFinish();


}
```

2) Create a reference of this interface in your First `AsyncTask`, in its `onPostExecute()`, call `reference.onProcessFinish();`

3) Call the other `AsyncTask` in `onProcessFinish()` in whichever class you are calling it, implement `OnAsyncOneComplete`

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this,See [here](http://nobalg.tumblr.com/post/98543748225/android-asynctasks-one-after-the-other) for more details

[image]

Write call to second asysncTask in the onPostExecute() method of the first asyncTask

---

### onPostExecute()

is method of AsyncTask which is executed when doInBackground() finishes its work

Comment: Alternatively, just call the same AsyncTask, but use a different parameter. For example, you use `n`, change it to `n+1`. So the same AsyncTask being called as long as `n < b - 1`.

Comment: So i have to pass n value as parameter to AsyncTask?